# Absolute Value program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner-level python programmer and I'm trying to make this short program that takes a number and prints its absolute value. Every time I run it, though, the compiler says the variable I made to hold the new number is not defined. IDK what I did wrong.

```
print("Welcome to the ABSOLUTE-VALUEINATOR")
num=float(input("Enter number to find absolute value: "))

if num<=0:
    new_num=num*-1
    print("The absolute value is: "+str(new_num))

else:
    print("The absolute value is: " +str(new_num))
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: If `num > 0`, `new_num` never gets defined.

Comment: In your `else` block you're trying to print `new_num` but you've never assigned it a value.

Comment: You are exactly right @khelwood, I was seriously questioning what I learned but that makes perfect sense. It works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to avoid defining a new variable for `new_num`. So the logic would be:

1. Convert the user input to float
2. If the given number is negative, then multiply it by `-1`
3. Print the result

So the code would be as follow:

```
print("Welcome to the ABSOLUTE-VALUEINATOR")

num = float(input("Enter number to find absolute value: "))

if num < 0:
    num *= -1

print("The absolute value is: " +str(num))
```

However, there is still a problem here. If the user enters an integer, this program will output a float.

e.g
Input: 125
Output: 125.0

If you just want to strip off the negative sign, you may just do the following:

```
print("Welcome to the ABSOLUTE-VALUEINATOR")

num = input("Enter number to find absolute value: ")

num = num.strip('-')

print("The absolute value is: " + num)
```

Comment: I've never seen the .strip() function in Python, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just require a little change. `new_num` to `num` in the else and it should work fine:

```
print("Welcome to the ABSOLUTE-VALUEINATOR")
num=float(input("Enter number to find absolute value: "))

if num<=0:
    new_num=num*-1
    print("The absolute value is: "+str(new_num))

else:
    print("The absolute value is: " +str(num))
```

This is because new_num is defined under if condition and if the condition is false, it never gets defined. A good approach however is to use the same variable both for changed number and actual input which would avoid all confusion:

```
print("Welcome to the ABSOLUTE-VALUEINATOR")
num=float(input("Enter number to find absolute value: "))

if num<=0:
    num=num*-1
    print("The absolute value is: "+str(num))

else:
    print("The absolute value is: " +str(num))
```